# BFS Tree Has Empty Output. What could be wrong?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a BFS algorithm. It's supposed to get a graph as an input. Then the output should be the BFS tree. It's also supposed to keep track of the parent and the level. I have tried to follow the pseudocode from Wikipedia. However, I am getting an empty BFS tree. Which part that I did wrong and how to fix it? Thanks. Here is the code snippet:

```
Graph Bicc::breadthFirstSearch(Graph& sparseGraph) {
    Graph tree;

    Vertex root = sparseGraph.getVertex(0);
    Vertex parent(-1);
    root.parent = &parent; 
    root.color = "white";
    root.level = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sparseGraph.getVertexCount(); i++){
        sparseGraph.getVertex(i).color = "white";
    }

    queue<Vertex> q;
    list<Vertex> neighbors = root.getNeighbors();
    root.color = "gray";
    q.push(root);                   

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        root = q.front();
        q.pop();

        for(auto& neighbor : neighbors)
        {
            if(neighbor.color == "white")
            {
                neighbor.color = "gray";
                neighbor.level = neighbor.level + 1;
                Vertex n_parent(0);
                neighbor.parent = &n_parent + 1;
                q.push(neighbor);
                tree.add(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Add some trace printouts to your code, and run it on some small inputs. Start by adding printouts to the loops, conditionals, etc., until you understand what's happening. Having someone debug your code for you, won't help you much in the long run.

Comment: don't you think that the neighbours should be determined inside the **while** loop?